# QgsMapCanvas layers disappear on canvas panning/zooming

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to write a plugin that will show an image based on its footprint in the vector layer.
Currently, I have a problem with QgsMapCanvas. Layer in QgsMapCanvas disappear when I pan/zoom canvas. Here's my code:

**myPlugin.py**

```py
def startOblique(self):
        self.dlgSec.canvas_dlg.show()
                
        self.dlgSec.canvas_dlg.enableAntiAliasing(True)
        
        newRaster = QgsRasterLayer(r'D:\basic\FRONT\B002_0891.tif','Raster1')
        print(newRaster)
        print(self.dlgSec.canvas_dlg)

        self.dlgSec.canvas_dlg.setLayers([newRaster])
        self.dlgSec.canvas_dlg.setExtent(newRaster.extent())
        
        self.dlgSec.canvas_dlg.refresh()
        self.dlgSec.canvas_dlg.waitWhileRendering()

def run(self):
        if self.first_start == True:
            self.first_start = False
            self.dlg = test1Dialog()
            self.dlgSec = test2Dialog()
            
        project = QgsProject.instance()
        # show the dialogs
        self.dlg.show()
        self.dlgSec.show()
        
        self.dlg.oblique_starter.clicked.connect(self.startOblique)
```

When I click `oblique_starter` button I get this:
[image: Oblique Image starter]
So, everything is fine by now. Raster is on the canvas.
When I try to pan/zoom on the canvas raster disappears so I get this:
[image]

Extra info:
When I execute simple code to show canvas and raster layer inside python console on QGIS I can pan and zoom layer and it doesn't disappear:

```py
canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
canvas.enableAntiAliasing(True)

newRaster = QgsRasterLayer(r'D:\basic\FRONT\B002_0891.tif','Raster1')

canvas.setExtent(newRaster.extent())
canvas.setLayers([newRaster])

canvas.resize(QSize(1366, 1064))
canvas.show()
```

What can I do to prevent the layer from disappearing from the canvas in my plugin?

Comment: I think mapCanvas is not refreshed, when you zoom or pan. Try to connect extentsChanged signal with a slot, which calls the refresh method.

Comment: I created such method like this
`def refresh_canvas(self):
    self.dlgSec.canvas_dlg.refresh()`
and signal:
`self.dlgSec.canvas.extentsChanged.connect(self.refresh_canvas)`

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help. @Detlev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `QgsMapCanvas` layers are cleared every time the extents are changed.
I don't know whether it is the desired behaviour.
So, I have to reinitiate `QgsMapCanvas` with layers every time extents change. Like this:

```py
def refreshOblique(self):
        print("extents changed")
        self.dlgSec.canvas_dlg.setLayers(self.layers)
        self.dlgSec.canvas_dlg.refresh()
        self.dlgSec.canvas_dlg.waitWhileRendering()
        print("extent center: {},{}".format(self.dlgSec.canvas_dlg.center().x(), self.dlgSec.canvas_dlg.center().y()))
        print("layers: {}".format(self.dlgSec.canvas_dlg.layers()))

def run(self):
        #previous code
        self.dlgSec.canvas_dlg.extentsChanged.connect(self.refreshOblique)
```

Without setting `setLayers` in `refreshOblique` function I get

```
layers: []
```

instead of raster:

```
 layers: [<qgis._core.QgsRasterLayer object at 0x00000234434853A8>]
```